# Pinescript zigzag values

Tags: pine-script

I wish to extract the last 3 high and lows of Zigzag.

In Metatrader4 it's possible to just call the builtin indicator to do it

```
zz = iCustom(symbol,PERIOD_M5,"ZigZag",ExtDepth,ExtDeviation,ExtBackstep,0,zzzz);
```

Any such possibility for Pinescript?

Answer (score 0):

There is no zigzag built-in in Pine, so you will need to use custom calcs and save the values as you go or use [`valuewhen()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_valuewhen) to fetch historical values once they have been calculated. You can [search the PL for zigzag indies](https://www.tradingview.com/scripts/zigzag/).